# Simplify the existing Hibernate Query Language (HQL)

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a hibernate query that I need to simplify as it has many `joins`. And I feel like the joins are unnecessary in some cases. I was trying to understand and simplify the query to get the same result after execution. However, I am not able to do so. Here is the query:

```
Select a from Animal a 
 left join Cat on cat.id = animal.id 
 left join Dog as dog on cat.id = dog.id
 left join Wolf on animal.id = wolf.id
 left join Monkey on animal.id = monkey.id
 left join Location as location on cat.location.id = location.id
 left join LocationZone as zone on zone.id = location.locationZone.id
 left join Place as place on place.id = monkey.place.id
 left join Location as newLocation on place.location.id =newLocation.location.id
 left join LocationZone as newZone on newZone.id = newLocation.LocationZone.id
WHERE ((cat.location.id is null and monkey.place.id is null) 
OR newLocation.locationZone.id = 1 or zone.locationZone.id = 1;
```

Here is something I tried:

```
Select a from Animal a where Type(a) in (Cat, Dog, Wolf, Monkey) and (a.location.id is null and a.place.id is null) or (a.location.locationZone.id = 1 or a.place.location.locationZone.id = 1);
```

However, I get empty results. I am not able to understand what the above query is trying to achieve, but I need to simplify the query as there are many joins. 
So, here is the basic information:

```
- Cat, Dog, Wolf, Monkey extends Animal
- Cat has location
- Location has locationZone
- Monkey has place
- Place has locaiton
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me understand the query and simplify it. Thank you very much.

Comment: JPQL in general does not require any ON clause, so no idea why you add those. Only you know the entities and relations ... And if you are not using JPA then kindly remove the JPA tag

Answer (score 0):

The first query that you show to us are using `JOIN`, that is unnecessary if you map the relationships in the Entities.

So, imagining that you map the relationship between each entity like you show in the query, the simplified JPQL query could be:

```
Select a from Animal a 
LEFT JOIN animal.cat cat
LEFT JOIN animal.dog
LEFT JOIN animal.wolf wolf
LEFT JOIN animal.monkey monkey
LEFT JOIN cat.location catLocation
LEFT JOIN catLocation.locationZone catLocationZone
LEFT JOIN monkey.place monkeyPlace
LEFT JOIN monkeyPlace.location monkeyLocation
LEFT JOIN monkeyLocation.locationZone monkeyLocationZone
LEFT JOIN monkeyLocation.location newMonkeyLocation
LEFT JOIN newMonkeyLocation.locationZone newMonkeyLocationZone
WHERE ((catLocation.id is null and monkeyPlace.id is null) 
OR monkeyLocationZone.id = 1 or newMonkeyLocationZone.id = 1;
```